# Uninstalling PyGTK from macpkg on Mac OS X

Tags: python, macos

I downloaded the pygtk pkg file from macpkg.sourceforge.net.

I want to remove this installation and instead use the version
that is provided by homebrew.

What files do I need to remove?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the BOM file in ~/Library/Receipts or /Library/Receipts
refer this article you can uninstall a pkg easily http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20100107090139622

if you can not find that, download the .pkg file again if you already delete

following these steps you can see what and where all the files install by this pkg

1. put the .pkg into temporary directory, /tmp e.g.
   `cp XZ.pkg /tmp`  for example, "XZ" is the .pkg filename
2. `cd /tmp`
3. expand the pkg file
   `pkgutil --expand XZ.pkg /tmp/XZpackage`
4. Go ahead and cd in the directory 
   `cd /tmp/XZpackage`
5. go into the directory XZ.pkg or local.pkg
   `cd local.pkg`
6. list the install files
   `lsbom Bom`

PS: simply you can use the Pacifist, this App will show you the result